# Grub menu appears even if i have hibernated Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, grub, hibernate

I had Windows 10 installed and then i installed latest version of Ubuntu 18.04.2, both works fine (first GRUB menu show up and then i can select which to boot up and if i select win then it takes me to windows OS selection screen where i can choose between Remix OS and Windows 10), the problem is that if I hibernate the Windows (which I always do), then also the GRUB menu shows up and I don't want that as you know that booting into the other OS while other is hibernated can result in huge loss of data.

Current : Grub shows up even if windows is hibernated.
What I want : Grub should only show up if all other OS are shutdown properly..that is Grub should not appear if windows is hibernated.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behavior for Linux. Modern Linux distros [are able to mount the Windows partition read-only](https://wiki.manjaro.org/How_to_mount_Windows_(NTFS)_filesystem_due_to_hibernation) if it was hibernated (i.e., *hiberfil.sys* exists), so Windows OS and data should be safe.

This allows you to run a Windows executable in wine, without need to copy to the ext*x* partition, even when hibernated, or to share data as read-only.

That said, as you state, it is good practice to perform a full shutdown, without hibernation, if dual-booting to Linux.

Comment: What you said I already mentioned in the question, I want if windows is hibernated then GRUB should not appear but it is, so tell me the steps to do that, so that i don't accidentally dual boot while one is hibernated.